# Mysql if entry exists

Tags: mysql

**Is there a possibility to check if record exists using mysql?**

```
rowName | number
----------------
dog     | 1
cat     | 2
```

For example:

If i have a variable `$var = 'dog'`, which already exists in my database, i want the system to add +1 number to the dog row.

On the other hand, when i have, for example, variable `$var='fish'`, which does not exist in my database, i want the system to insert new row `'fish'` with number 1.

I am wondering if there is one query alternative to two different queries using php conditions. I assume it would be faster running only one mysql query.

Comment: You don't need to check. Just use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  For example

> ```
> INSERT INTO table (rowName, `number`) VALUES ('$var', 1)
>   ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `number` = `number` + 1;
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> // you can check record exists or not

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT rowName FROM table WHERE rowName="$var");
```

> // you can make one query also

```
INSERT INTO table(`rowName`, `number`) VALUES ("$var", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `number` = `number`+ 1;
```